Printing N Width Columns Depending on Results Returned
I'm working with ODBC to build a small SQL client capable of executing basic queries on an SQL Server. However, when I print returned results from a query, my columns and rows are unevenly spaced out.
For instance, when I execute EXEC sp_helprotect 'xp_dirtree';, my results appear like the following:
Owner   Object  Grantee Grantor ProtectType     Action  Column
sys     xp_dirtree      public  dbo     Grant           Execute

The columns are all over the place and it's often times hard to make out which column's data belongs to which column.
I'm currently using tabs to print each column and its data which I know is the issue.. However, is there any better way going around this and evenly printing results depending on the width of each column? How can I space each column according to it's witdth and then print the next column in the set?
My current way of handling things is with a tab \t.
// Get total count of columns from result set
SQLUSMALLINT cCount;
SQLNumResultCols(hStmt, &cCount);

// Describe each column
SQLCHAR cName[128] = { '\0' };
SQLUSMALLINT cColumn;
for (cColumn = 1; cColumn <= cCount; cColumn++) {
    SQLDescribeColA(hStmt, cColumn, cName, sizeof(cName), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    printf("%s\t", cName);
}

// Fetch and print rows
SQLCHAR rResults[8192] = { '\0' };
SQLRETURN rRet = SQLFetch(hStmt);
while (rRet != SQL_NO_DATA && rRet != SQL_ERROR) {
    printf("\n"); // New line for row information
    for (cColumn = 1; cColumn <= cCount; cColumn++) {
        SQLGetData(hStmt, cColumn, SQL_C_CHAR, rResults, sizeof(rResults), NULL);
        printf("%s\t", rResults);
        // Empty array for next row
        memset(rResults, '\0', sizeof(rResults));
    }
    rRet = SQLFetch(hStmt);
}


You can use the field-width specifier, like %10s (or %-10s depending on your needs).
And if the columns should all have different widths then use an array with the widths and use the %*s format:
printf("%*s", widths[cColumn], rResults);

Use the same widths for the column headers, and they would all be aligned.

Thank you, will try to get the width of each column into an array and print it this way

SQLDescribeCol will return the size of the column in the 7th parameter, so you just need a way to store that with the column name.  Might want to create a type to associate name and width (and any other properties) such as
SQLUSMALLINT cCount;
SQLNumResultCols(hStmt, &cCount);

struct col {
  SQLCHAR name[128]; 
  SQLULEN width;
} colData[cCount]; // since this is a VLA, we can't initialize it

SQLUSMALLINT cColumn;
for (cColumn = 1; cColumn <= cCount; cColumn++) {
    SQLDescribeColA(hStmt, cColumn, colData[cColumn-1].name, sizeof colData[cColumn-1].name, NULL, NULL, NULL, &colData[cColumn-1].width, NULL);
    printf("%*s ", colData[cColumn-1].width, colData[cColumn-1].name);
}
...
        SQLGetData(hStmt, cColumn, SQL_C_CHAR, rResults, sizeof(rResults), NULL);
        printf("%*s ", colData[cColumn-1].width, rResults);
...


Suggestion: Allocate } colData[ 1 + cCount ]; and simplify to colData[ cColumn ] in several places. colData[0] is just unused padding to simplify indexing.
